# Beijing Traffic Data

Tags: data-request, transportation, traffic, china

I'm looking for a reliable source for traffic data in Beijing. In some papers that I've read, a particular dataset is mentioned. From the articles:

> "The traffic network is located between the Second Ring Road and Third Ring Road in Beijing."
>
> " 2-min travel speed data collected from three remote traffic microwave sensors located on a southbound segment of a fourth ring road in Beijing City."
>
> " a dataset consisting of probe vehicle data collected in the urban network of Beijing, China, during one week from June 1st (Monday) to 7th (Sunday), 2015"
>
> "north-east transportation network of Beijing"

I've searched the internet to find this dataset of vehicle speed in Beijing and found the following links in Chinese:

http://jtw.beijing.gov.cn/

http://cgs.bjjtgl.gov.cn/chgs/Main.jsp

Unfortunately, Chinese is not my native language and I cannot explore these sites easily.

Can someone fluent in Chinese explore these sites and see if I can request traffic speed data of previous months? Can I email them and request this data?

Also, here is a contact and some emails in this link:
http://www.bjjtgl.gov.cn/jgj/96629/index.html